# Optimize initialization of C array with expressions

Tags: c, arrays, optimization

I'm doing a program transformation from a language that allows expressions in array initializers to C99, which doesn't.

Currently, the way I'm handling this is to create an __arrayInit function and then generate a very large number of these inside:

```
array[0] = x + y * z; // Sample Expression
array[1] = a / b + c; // Another
array[2] = 5; // sometimes there's a constant
...
```

Often there are hundreds of these individual initializations.  Is there a better way of doing this that executes faster?  Kudos if it compiles faster as well.

**Edit:**  The expressions are sometimes non-constant and can have variables and function calls in them.

Comment: _Constant_ expressions are allowed in array initializers.

Comment: Is your array static or it is being defined inside a function? In the latter case non-constant initializers are allowed in C99, here is [an example](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Initializers.html#Initializers) from GCC docs.

Comment: @p.kolya, any expressions are allowed in function scope.

Comment: It's a pointer in a struct that gets malloc'd in the __arrayInit function.

Comment: Don't expect speed. For every element, it has to evaluate the expression and then store it. That's so no matter how it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99 allows expressions in initializer

```
int sarray[] = {
   [0] = x + y * z, // Sample Expression
   [1] = a / b + c, // Another
   [2] = 5, // sometimes there's a constant
};
```

is valid syntax.

**Edit:**
If it is an `auto` variable any expression that has a type that is assignment compatible to the base type of the array is allowed.

For arrays with `static` storage class (either global arrays or local arrays that are additionally declared with `static`) you can use constant expressions composed of:

- any type of literals such as `23`, `1E-45`, `"hello"`
- enumeration constants
- address constants of global variables or functions

*Not* working are `const` qualified variables.

Comment: Do those have to equate to a constant?

Comment: @SamWashburn: Only if the array is in global scope. If it is in function scope any expression that has a type that is assignment compatible to the base type of the array is allowed.

Comment: @JensGustedt in c99, if in function scope but with the `static` storage specifier, initializers also have to be constant expressions. In c89, aggreate or union types initializers always have to be constant expressions (even if the storage duration is automatic).

Comment: @ouah, right reformulated to refer to the storage class. For C89 also correct, but the question explicitly talked about C99.

Comment: s/function scope/block scope/ in my last comment